# MS CRM Data Import Negative currency

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I set up a Data mapping for data import in a custom entity.  However, some currency amounts are being rejected if their format includes parentheses (signifying negative values) or commas.  Is there any way I can tweak the xml in the data mapping to allow for these different formats?  I'm working in MS CRM 4.  Thanks!

Amount USDnew_period
Process

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you modify (Data cleansing by String Manipulation) the csv before submitting?

Comment: We've since upgraded to CRM2011 and don't experience this issue.